# Android Studio how to have marker infoWindow open by default without clicking on it?

Tags: java, android

This is a method which handles a new location within my code, should I have the addition of the marker infoWindow elsewhere in order for it to appear when loading up the activity or is there something simplistic I am missing? Thank you!

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);


    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker_mini)));
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            List<Address> currentLocation = null;
            try {
                currentLocation = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            String address = currentLocation.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = currentLocation.get(0).getLocality();
            String postal = currentLocation.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String country = currentLocation.get(0).getCountryCode();

            TextView Address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
            Address.setText(address + ", " + city + ",\n " + postal + ", " + country);


            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `InfoWindowAdapter` *before* calling `marker.showInfoWindows()` ?

Comment: Aaaaand that solved it! Haha can't believe I didn't see that, cheers for the quick fix!